# Kubernetes on AWS by Kops - dynamic provisioning gp2 fails for single node cluster; PVC is pending;

Tags: kubernetes, kops, kubernetes-pvc

My PVCs are in `Pending` state all the time.

`kubectl describe pvc project-s3-pvc` gives:

```
Name:          project-s3-pvc
Namespace:     default
StorageClass:  gp2
Status:        Pending
Volume:        
Labels:        <none>
Annotations:   kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
                 {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"PersistentVolumeClaim","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"project-s3-pvc","namespace":"default"},"spec":{"ac...
               volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-provisioner: kubernetes.io/aws-ebs
Finalizers:    [kubernetes.io/pvc-protection]
Capacity:      
Access Modes:  
Events:        <none>
Mounted By:    project-s3-86ccd56868-skvv5
✔ /data/project [kubernetes-aws L|✚ 10⚑ 66
```

`kubectl get storageclass` gives:

```
NAME            PROVISIONER             AGE
default         kubernetes.io/aws-ebs   1h
gp2 (default)   kubernetes.io/aws-ebs   1h
```

I am running 1 node cluster started by Kops:

```
kops create cluster --node-count 0 --zones eu-west-1a ${NAME} --master-size t2.large

# Change size from 2 to 0, since above node-count does seem to be ignored
kops edit ig --name=${NAME} nodes

kops edit cluster ${NAME}

# Add this to cluster specification
iam:
  allowContainerRegistry: true
  legacy: false

kops update cluster ${NAME} --yes

kubectl taint nodes --all node-role.kubernetes.io/master-node
```

Then I add PVCs e.g.:

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: bomcheck-s3-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 30Gi
```

Kops version: `Version 1.11.0 (git-2c2042465)`

EDIT:
When I do try to create PV manually:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv-manual
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  awsElasticBlockStore:
    fsType: ext4        
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Delete
  storageClassName: gp2
  capacity:
    storage: 30Gi
```

I am getting the: `ValidationError(PersistentVolume.spec.awsElasticBlockStore): missing required field "volumeID" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.AWSElasticBlockStoreVolumeSource;`

Does it mean I need to create the volume ahead in the AWS manually? I would like volume to by dynamically provisioned.

Any idea how to debug why the PVC/PV can't be provisioned on behalf of my AWS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem does seem to be related to the fact that I am running just one master node.
When I start cluster using: `kops create cluster --zones eu-west-1a ${NAME} --master-size t2.large`, so it does start 1 master and 2 nodes. The problem doesn't appear.

I am not sure what's directly the root cause of the problem, since there isn't anything preventing one node from having external EBS volumes. This might be bug in the `kops` itself, since just one master node is rather exception instead of rule.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, there is no `Volume:` bound to your PVC it means that automatic volume provisioning failed and PV is not created which should be created with your Dynamic Provisioning configuration. You need to see created PV name on the `Volume:` section of describe command. 
Unfortunately there are no logs or events that show the problem.

[image]

I would suggest you for troubleshooting to create storageclass manually with gp2 to see if it works with below yaml then define `storageClassName` on your PVC yaml file like below:

**storageclass-manual-gp2.yaml:**

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: gp2-manual
parameters:
  type: gp2
provisioner: kubernetes.io/aws-ebs
reclaimPolicy: Delete
volumeBindingMode: Immediate
```

**Apply:**

```
kubectl apply -f storageclass-manual-gp2.yaml
```

**pv-manual.yaml:**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv-manual
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  awsElasticBlockStore:
    fsType: ext4
  capacity:
    storage: 30Gi
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Delete
  storageClassName: gp2-manual #your new storageclass name
```

**Apply:**

```
kubectl apply -f pv-manual.yaml
```

**Describe PVC:**

```
kubectl describe pvc pvc-gp2-manual
```

[image]

If no success, also I would suggest you to try different [storage type for AWS EBS](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/#aws-ebs).

Comment: Thanks. I am getting the `missing required field "volumeID" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.AWSElasticBlockStoreVolumeSource` which I am trying to resolve. It does look like it does expect me to create volume ahead instead of provisioning it dynamically.